# Can't ping VirtualBox Client Operating System

Tags: 12.04, file-sharing

I have installed Virtual Box on host Ubuntu 12.04 and RHEL 5.5 as client.
I need to do file sharing between em.

And I can access the shared folder of Ubuntu from RHEL using Shared Folder Service builtin VB.

[image: Shared Folder]

And now I want to access a file that is on RHEL but the thing is this I can't access it.

And I can't even ping any.

Ubuntu HostName:: Inspiron-N5110
RHEL Hostname :: Redhat

## Ping from ubuntu to Redhat

> umair@Inspiron-N5110:~$ ping Redhat
>
> ping: unknown host Redhat

## Ping from Redhat to Ubuntu

> ping Inspiron-N5110
>
> ping: unknown host Inspiron-N5110

Network is NAT

[image: Network Image]

Actually that is quite strange that I can't even ping Host system itself means when i do
*ping Inspiron-N5110* it replies that **ping: unknown host Inspiron-N5100** and same is the case for Client System.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have selected NAT (see screenshot 2). Change it to bridged and select your network interface. Then both machines are in the same network and can ping each other.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work Network Adapter changed to Bridged and NW connected to eth0. But no use. Any other suggestion

Comment: you can't ping a nat interface. 

Select bridge mode and select the correct interface.

don't forget to check your firewall in the guest machine and host machine. In redhat don't forget to check apparmor/selinux too

Comment: One more thing I would like to add also set the PROMISCUOUS MODE to  ALLOW ALL.